# How to post whole database on retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, web-services, retrofit2, android-room

I want to post all the enteries of SQLite. I am using Room database library and saving marks and other info into the Database. After completion I want them to push(POST) all database into the web server. I am using Retrofit2. I want to post all the enteries of database when user click push or submit button.

Comment: How much data do you store on local db? For multi-user, how do you solve entity id conflict when pushing local data to server side?

Comment: I am using String as a id and using UUID to resolve this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research on retrofit I have found that we can create interface on POST call which take list of model which we want to post and than retrofit itself handle all the implementation all we have to do is to pass list to the call.